# JavaScript plugin doesn't work in inner pages of my ionic project

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, owl-carousel

Im using a JavaScript slider / Owl Carousel, but the problem is that it's not working in the inner pages in my Ionic project.

In other words, when I paste the HTML code in the home page of the project it works perfectly, but if I paste the same code in the inner pages like "profile page," it's not working.

I have called the slider CSS and JavaScript file from the "index.html" page which is inside the "src" folder.

(My JavaScript plugin is working on the home page because HomePage is the root page, and profile is an inner page. If I change the ProfilePage as the root page my JavaScript plugin will work.)

Below is my index page from which I have called the owl.slider CSS and JS files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CALL THE OWL.SLIDER FILE -->
  <link href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CALL THE OWL.SLIDER FILE -->


  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
      It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <!-- CALL THE OWL.SLIDER FILE -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 1000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true
      });
      $('.play').on('click', function() {
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
      })
      $('.stop').on('click', function() {
        owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
      })
    })
  </script>
  <!-- CALL THE OWL.SLIDER FILE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Home page and index.html page are in same folder or not? where you use this code?

Comment: home page is inside the pages folder.  and the index.html is inside the src folder which is outside the pages

Comment: my javasript plugin working in the home because HomePage is the root page, and profile is the inner pages. if i will change the ProfilePage as root page my javascript plugin will work..

Comment: check your slider css and javascript file path which you provide in link and script section.

Comment: im not getting where else should i paste the css and javascript paths

Comment: can you show your folder structure.?

Comment: location of my index.html "(D:\myapp\src and then index.html)" and location of homePage in the folder (D:\myapp\src\pages\home and then home.html) and profile page location is (D:\labx\src\pages\profile and profile.html)

Comment: better you read my question once again ... please